# Dynamic google line chart not showing up with php and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization, linegraph

I am using google charts to display a line graph on my locally hosted web page. I am using mysqli to take the data from my phpmyadmin database then echoing this into the row spaces in the javascript.

This is the code within my html body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>

<script>
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

    function drawBasic() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Speed');

        data.addRows([                
            <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT id_rides, speed, date_completed FROM rides_done WHERE (id_users = $_SESSION[id])";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $date = $row['date_completed'];
                $speed = floatval($row['speed']);
                echo "['".$date."', ".$speed."],";
            }
            ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
            title: 'Ride date'
            },
            vAxis: {
            title: 'Average speed'
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

</script>
```

The problem is that nothing is being displayed on the web page.

I know that the query works as I tried this on it's own outside of the javascript and this was output: [results of sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M80Xg.png)

Before I added the dynamic element of the chart it was working fine with just random lists of data.

I was expecting to see a line graph with 'Average Speed' on the y-axis and 'Ride date' on the x-axis with 7 datapoints but nothing was displayed.

It seems that js is particular about datatypes here so I'm wondering if it is something to do with either of the following lines - both of which I have been fiddling around with to no avail.

```
echo "['".$date."', ".$speed."],";

data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Speed');
```

Thank you very much. All suggestions and ideas are very welcome. As is probably evident I am very new to Javascript so likely to be making some stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I would say: As you appear to wish to use a date within the dataTable perhaps setting that as a `date` type column would be better and casting the value from the db query as a date using `new Date(str)`. I'd also suggest that you use `json_encode` once you have run the db query to create a JSON object rather than manually building a string as you do above - one downside to that approach is the trailing comma which **might** cause issues.

I rattle together a working demo using bogus data from my db to emulate what you were trying to do here. The SQL query uses aliases to take arbitrary data and name it as you do so the Javascript remains fairly much the same.

With the JSON data it is easy to iterate through the Object using `Object.keys( json ).forEach()` type structure ( I apologise if this is new to you )

```
<?php

    #add a db connection
    chdir('../../dbo');
    require 'db-conn-details.php';
    require 'mysqli-conn.php';
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script src='//www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
        <script></script>
        <title>Google charts.....</title>
        <style>
            #chart_div{
                width:800px;height:600px
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='chart_div'></div>
        
        <script>
            <?php
            
                $sql = 'SELECT `speed`, `date_completed` FROM `rides_done` WHERE ( `id_users` = $_SESSION[id] )';
                $sql = 'select `dr` as `speed`, date(`lasteditdate`) as `date_completed` from `testtable` limit 20'; # example sql...
                
                $result = $link->query( $sql );
                $json = json_encode( $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC ) );
                printf('const json=%s;', $json );
            ?>
        
        
            google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] } );
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( drawBasic );
        
            function drawBasic() {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Speed');
        
                Object.keys( json ).forEach( key=>{
                    let obj=json[ key ];
                    data.addRow( [ new Date( obj.date_completed ), parseFloat( obj.speed ) ] );
                })
        
                var options = {
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Ride date'
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                        title: 'Average speed'
                    }
                };
        
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart( document.getElementById('chart_div') );
                    chart.draw( data, options );
            }
            
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above yielded a chart like this:

[image: example chart]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I have gone with using Canvas.js instead of the google charts as I still wasn't having success so now it is working. Appreciate the help anyway.